# Not being able to set the path for an image related to a model properly in Django

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I need to set a profile picture for a model in Django. I am using Pillow. My problem is that the path that I set on models.py (where the images go when I upload them using admin) is not the same as the one used by the template and so the images never show.

My static folder is in the app's folder (this is a simple project with just one app) but admin uploads the images in some folder outside the app folder.

This my code in models.py:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('static/artists/images', str(instance.id), filename)

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    soundcloud = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    current_roster = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.encode('utf8')
```

And this is the code in the template:

```
{% if artist.profile_picture %}
                <img src="{{ artist.profile_picture.url }}" alt="Artist pic" style="width: 200px;">
{% endif %}
```

Can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: django provides 2 separate sets of files: `static` and `media` and their usages are different:

- static files are served with your project code and are connected to that code. This can be for example CSS files, JavaScript, images that are part of your style or HTML layout in general.
- media files are uploaded into your project by scripts, in admin etc and are connected with data in your database. This can be photo in your article, avatar of user on your site etc.

Both groups of files should be served directly by your HTTP server. Both files are kept inside global folders for each project - in case of static files: they are collected from all of used apps, in case of media files: they are uploaded from web. None of them should be served from app directory.

Secondly: you shouldn't specify static or media folder in upload_to, it will be added by django based on your settings.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the static folder to my project folder (instead of the app folder) and all styles and everything went missing. How do you set that up?

Comment: Where did I said that you should move them? Leave them in app folder. Create some new directory inside your project (i personally prefer to create dir named `public` and inside 2 dirs: `static` and `media`), set path to that directory inside your settings file (as `STATIC_ROOT` setting) and run `./manage.py collectstatic`. All static files from all apps will be copied here.

Answer (score 0):

This should work well for you and you are working with media files not static which I made all the proper switches down below, static files are css js, and images not downloaded by the users themselves. But if you have any questions please leave a comment.

settings.py - add this to your context_processors, and make sure you media root and media URL are configured this way

```
  TEMPLATES = [
      {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
              'django.template.context_processors.debug',
              'django.template.context_processors.request',
              'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
              'django.core.context_processors.media', ###add this string here 
              'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
         },
      },
   ]

  MEDIA_URL='/media/'
  MEDIA_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')]
```

models.py - media/media/images/1/file.jpeg <--- the path, the rest of your models look fine

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
  return os.path.join('/media/images', str(instance.id), filename)
  ###### added media to the path #######
```

template.html - make the changes I made to your html the path should show up as media/media/images/instance.id/profile_picture.jpeg, the instance.id and file name are made up but you get what I am saying.

```
  {% if artist.profile_picture %}
      <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ artist.profile_picture }}" alt="Artist pic" style="width: 200px;">
  {% else %}
      <p> you can download a picture one day. </p>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to almost work as the source of the image (src) is in the media folder but admin now uploads the image to a folder named images (not inside the media folder) in my project folder.

Comment: simple fix if you want that I will edit my answer real fast

Comment: Yes, please. I'd be very grateful if you did that. Thanks!

Comment: Thank very much for the edit but the problem still persists. Anyway, I'm sorry for bothering you and thank you for your attention. I'm pretty new at Django (and programming in general).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It worked! I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer as my "reputation" is too low.